# Updating an answer with additional up-to-date information gets rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I have seen this rejection for my edits twice this week when I tried to update an answer that had gone out of date. I am confused, both as to why they got rejected and why with *that* reasoning.

First, an update to [include](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18701826) the now standardized `wheel` DOM event into an answer asking about page zoom prevention, while adding context to it and the other events, pulling out the wrongly nested event handler and - which I agree I [should not have included](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/5236247) - syntax changes.

Meant to address the author? No, they haven't been online for ~4 years, and it's to update old information while not destroying support for older browsers. Comment? Didn't feel that right to me, esp. because it wouldn't have caught the same attention due to the "this works" "this doesn't work" comments. Different answer? Maybe, but why not update the accepted answer with the correct info so it's easier for users?

Secondly, and today, an [update](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18736349) to an old answer that explains usage that was deprecated 3 years ago in a manner so the newer solution available since then is the default and only choice in the 1.0 version.

Again, not meant for the author, they're not there. Not meant as a comment - a mention of the other, 0-rated answer that just says it's deprecated while providing a different approach to it all. Not as an answer, because it was essentially a version-preserving update of the answer. Folks using 0.12 or lower can discern their code from the title. If I posted a separate answer, beginning users of 1.0+ would try it out, see a rather confusing error message, and then go back and scroll through the other answers again, which takes time.

---

I hope this did not come across as a whiny "Why was I not accepted pls accept me". That is not my intent. What I want to know is both whether my interpretation of the reject reason is correct (if it is, in my opinion the 'should have been an answer' part could well be extracted), and how I should go about edits like this in the future.

Comment: If you have an answer that applies to a newer version, why not post a new answer?

Comment: @Yivi Although posting a new answer usually is appropriate, the Help Center's [Guide to Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) says that edits should be used to keep questions and answers up to date, and later says that posts should be edited to add updates as the post ages. So an edit to update an answer that's gone out of date may be acceptable, supposing of course that the edit adds correct good-quality information and doesn't detract from the author's intent. However, I don't think you can go wrong by posting a new answer entirely.

Comment: @DavyM I still feel posting a new answer would be much better and appropriate than forever updating the same answer adding new bits as they become available. And I believe both examples by the OP **are** putting words in the original answerers mouths.

Comment: @Yivi I did not post a new answer because I felt that the burden on the user is simply less. That it'd be easier for them to find the for-them-important in the accepted answer, not one that is lower down on the page. Because, to me, the ''or add updates as the post ages" line in the Guide to Editing is for exactly that. And also, I somewhat see your reasoning about putting something in OPs mouths, but, isn't that always the case? I think drawing the line in a case like that is quite difficult, and esp. in case 1 again, I added info so it works even today, bc. like comments said it hadn't